# Are fields projections in spacetime of higher dimesions?

Tags: spacetime, field-theory, spacetime-dimensions

I am initiating my learning on QFT and my question might be really basic, but I am having difficulties finding an answer, I would appreciate any help to find this in the literature.

Here is my question:

If all dimensions are independent and co-exist (here and now).
If humans are not able to see all dimensions, but we might be able to measure them.

My question is when we observe projections of other dimensions on spacetime they should be observed as fields, right? And in spacetime any equation should be an equation of motion to make sense, right?

If this is true...

Can we find these equations (electromagnetic field, for example) accounting for the dimensions the projection misses?

I appreciate the time anyone put to answer my questions.

Thanks!

---

Let me try to rephrase my question.

Imagine a 2D parabolic equation y=x^2. If you look at it as 1D, in x, what you would see a lot of values "closer to each other" (higher density) as x goes -∞ and +∞.

In my mind, this density of values would look like a "field" in x, instead of being described as a higher dimension function.

If you have measured enough values of x, is it possible to get to y=x^2?

If fields are projections in spacetime, can we find the other dimensions if we have enough measurements?

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean by "project" in this context?

Comment: What I meant with "project" is to find the possible variables/values accounting for these dimensions in the equations. If a field is a projection of a higher number of dimensions, is there a way to find the original equation accounting for the dimension(s) we miss with a projection?

Comment: One can make a wire model of a tesseract. Conceptually we know that it is the projection of a four dimensional object in three dimensions, but there is nothing physically observable in this model that enforces one to see it as the projection of a higher dimensional object. I suspect that a similar situation applies to field theories in higher dimensions.

Comment: thanks @flippiefanus!

Comment: What is an "edge" in this context? values closer to the edge of what?

Comment: what I meant with "edge" is the havier part of the projection, as there are more frequent values of x "closer to each other" (density) as y increases. You re right, "edge" might not be the best word here. I have tried to change the text. Let me know if it makes better sense now.

Comment: Any suggestions on articles or literature?